# Scrapy shell does not have hxs or xxs as available objects

Tags: python, scrapy, ipython

First, I am following the tutorial from: http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.16/intro/tutorial.html.

I run:

```
scrapy shell http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/
```

From the tutorial it says: "The shell also instantiates two selectors, one for HTML (in the hxs variable) and one for XML (in the xxs variable) with this response. So let’s try them:"

My output however does not have hxs or xxs as available objects:

```
[s] Available Scrapy objects:
[s]   crawler    <scrapy.crawler.Crawler object at 0x03B33750>
[s]   item       {}
[s]   request    <GET http://tvtorrents.com/loggedin/show.do?id=3845>
[s]   response   <200 http://tvtorrents.com/login.do>
[s]   settings   <scrapy.settings.Settings object at 0x02718790>
[s]   spider     <Spider 'default' at 0x3e30190>
[s] Useful shortcuts:
[s]   shelp()           Shell help (print this help)
[s]   fetch(req_or_url) Fetch request (or URL) and update local objects
[s]   view(response)    View response in a browser
```

I am expecting:

```
[s]   hxs        <HtmlXPathSelector (http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/) xpath=None>
[s]   xxs        <XmlXPathSelector (http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/) xpath=None>
```

as "available objects".

This prevents me from refining the output like so:

```
In [1]: hxs.select('//title')
Out[1]: [<HtmlXPathSelector (title) xpath=//title>]
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you're going to down vote my question at least tell me what you didn't like or how this question could have been better!

Answer (score 2):

It is a version problem: the tutorial you are using was written for Scrapy 0.16 and you are using the newer version of Scrapy. Use this link for the latest available tutorial:  http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html.

And, FYI, you should use [`response.xpath()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.TextResponse.xpath) now:

```
$ scrapy shell http://stackoverflow.com
>>> response.xpath('//title')
[<Selector xpath='//title' data=u'<title>Stack Overflow</title>'>]
>>> response.xpath('//title').extract()
[u'<title>Stack Overflow</title>']
>>> response.xpath('//title/text()').extract()
[u'Stack Overflow']
```